# Kannel Configuration for Mysql is showing error

Tags: mysql, kannel

kannel.conf file connected and going well

in dlr-storage if we put as dlr-storage = internal than bearerbox is working

and if we put dlr-storage = mysql than bearerbox is getting the following error

DLR: storage type 'mysql' is not supported and bearerbox is stopped

kindly tell me how t resolve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe your problem [more precisely](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Kannel with `--with-mysql` and possibly `--with-mysql-dir` before compiling, that's why your current version doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to install Kannel properly using [this](http://nagendrababuimmadi.blogspot.com/2012/12/steps-to-install-kannel-sms-gateway.html) blog. Keep your configuration files, just use this one when you are reinstalling Kannel.
If you wanna know how to remove Kannel properly, check [this](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/k/kannel/uninstall/index.html) site.

```
./configure --with-mysql
```

Comment: You should put the relevant parts of your external sources inside your answer, as link only answers can be invalidated when the linked page changes.